# solution to DE: $y'(y^2-x^2+2ax)=2y(a-x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this nonlinear first order differential equation:

$$y'(x)(y(x)^2-x^2+2ax)=2y(x)(a-x)$$
where $a\in R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $y \ne 0$, we can divide the ODE by $y^2$ and obtain a total differential:
$$
y'(y^2 - x^2 + 2ax) + 2y(x-a) = 0
\implies y' + \frac{-y'}{y^2}(x^2 - 2ax) + \frac{1}{y}( x^2 - 2ax)' = 0\\
\iff \frac{d}{dx}\left( y + \frac{x^2 - 2ax}{y}\right) = 0$$

This means for some integration constant $b$, we have
$$y + \frac{x^2 - 2ax}{y} = 2b\quad\iff\quad y^2 - 2by + x^2 - 2ax = 0\tag{*1}$$
The leads to a family of solutions for the ODE which are circles passing through the origin with center on the line $x = a$.

If $y(x) = 0$ for some $x \ne 0$ or $2a$, the ODE reduces to $y'(x) = 0$. 
This implies in additional to above family of circles, there are three more solutions corresponds to the line segments:
$$(-\infty, 0) \to (0,0),\quad (0,0) \to (2a,0)\quad\text{ and }\quad (2a,0) \to (\infty, 0)$$

**Behind the Scene**

About how to notice the total difference, I didn't in the beginning.

My first attempt is cast the ODE to a parametric form, introduce some
auxiliary variable $t$ and look for solution of an associated ODE:
$$\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t) &= y(t)^2 - (x(t)-a)^2 + a^2\\
\dot{y}(t) &= -2y(t)(x(t)-a)
\end{cases}\tag{*2}$$
The expression on RHS look like the real/imaginary part of square of a complex number.
If one define $z(t) = x(t) - a + iy(t)$, one can simplify $(*2)$ to something relatively standard:
$$\dot{z}(t) + z(t)^2 = a^2$$
One can solve it and arrive at the implicit solution in RHS of $(*1)$. Rearranging the terms lead to LHS of $(*1)$ and make me realize the ODE can be rewritten as a total differential.

Comment: My problem was that I didn't saw that you can obtain a total differential here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @MartynasRiauka neither can I in the beginning, see update of answer how  the total differential is discovered.

Comment: That's clever. I totally enjoyed the way are you thinking. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $y$ is polynomial in $x$. If $O(y)=n$, then $O(y')=n-1$

$O(LHS)=(n-1)+2n=3n-1$

$O(RHS)=n+1$

$O(LHS)=O(RHS) \Rightarrow 3n-1=n+1 \Rightarrow n=1$

So let's try $y=px+q$, with $y'=p$

$p \left ((px+q)^2-x^2+2ax \right)=2(px+q)(a-x)$

$p \left (p^2x^2+2pqx+q^2-x^2+2ax \right)=2apx-2px^2+2aq-2qx$

$p^3x^2+2p^2qx+pq^2-px^2+2apx=2apx-2px^2+2aq-2qx$

$p^3x^2+px^2+2p^2qx+2qx+pq^2-2aq=0$

Comparing coefficients of $x^2$: $p^3+p=0 \Rightarrow p \in \{0,i,-i\}$

Comparing coefficients of $x$: $2p^2q+2q=0 \Rightarrow q=0$ or $p \in \{i,-i\}$

Constant terms: $pq^2-2aq=0$

If $p=0$ then $q=0$ from above and this equation is satisfied.

If $p=\pm i$ then $q$ need not be $0$

$\pm iq^2-2aq=0 \Rightarrow q=0$ or $\pm iq-2a=0 \Rightarrow q=\frac{2a}{\pm i} \Rightarrow q= \mp 2ai$

Possible solutions are:

$y=0$

$y=ix$

$y=-ix$

$y=i(x-2a)$

$y=i(2a-x)$

None of these is really what you want, so need to think again...